# How to install an executable in yarn workspace that is specified in a package inside of it?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Following folder structure and files are given:

```
.
├── package.json
└── scripts
    ├── hello-word.js
    └── package.json
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "yarn-bin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "workspaces": [
    "scripts"
  ]
}
```

```json
// scripts/package.json
{
  "name": "@yarn-bin/scripts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
    "hello-world": "./hello-world.js"
  }
}
```

```js
// scripts/hello-world.js
#!/usr/bin/env -S npx node

console.log("Hello World")
```

This is a very simple `yarn workspace` setup where an executable  is specified in a workspace package (`"bin"` in `scripts/package.json`).
Executing `./hello-world.js` works just fine (with prior `chmod +x hello-world.js`).

**Question**

Is it possible to install this executable in the workspace itself?

(To break it down: I would like to execute the script from anywhere in the workspace e.g. with `npx hello-world`)

Comment: If you add the script with `bin` key in the package.json into a workspace folder you will be able to use it via `yarn hello-world` or `npm run hello-world` yes

Comment: But your hash bang should be `#!/usr/bin/env node` in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the comments what you got here is almost complete.
You did have a typo in your file name but I assume that's a typo that happened while you copied this over to SO.
I did change the [hash bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to make sure you run this via node.

You cannot run this via npx as npx will go online and look through the registry.

```
.
├── package.json
└── scripts
    ├── hello-world.js # not "hello-word.js"
    └── package.json
```

Root `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "yarn-bin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "hello": "yarn hello-world"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "scripts"
  ]
}
```

`scripts/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@yarn-bin/scripts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
    "hello-world": "./hello-world.js"
  }
}
```

And `script/hello-world.js`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Hello World")
```

With that setup running `yarn hello` in the root folder will yield:

```
$ yarn hello
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn hello-world
$ /path/to/folder/node_modules/.bin/hello-world
Hello World
✨  Done in 0.25s.
```

While I added an npm script into the root `package.json` you can also execute bins via just running `yarn hello-world` anywhere from within your project.

Comment: Wow, this didn't work at first sight because I needed to delete `node_modules` first and run `yarn install`. It seems like `yarn install` doesn't pick up changes of files specified in `bin`  part of `package.json`. Is there a way to tell `yarn` to also check if `bin` files have changed? Also I actually use `#!/usr/bin/env -S npx esr` or `#!/usr/bin/env -S npx ts-node` in my scripts. Is there really no way to execute the scripts with `npx`? Are there other options here? I would like to make this process really simple for all devs without any daunting extra steps.

Comment: I don't know enough about npx but to my understanding it is built to go and fetch things that are not installed. How is running an npm script worse than running an npx script? Also if I make changes to the `hello-world.js` file I can see those changes immediately when running `yarn hello` or `yarn hello-world`.

Comment: The problem is not `npx` vs. `npm script` but rather the necessity to install a cli (here `node` or `esr` or `ts-cnode`) globally. `npx` looks for executables in the current project first and then globally. You can actually make this work with following hash-bang: `#!npx esr`. This requires you to install the packages locally though e.g. `yarn add esbuild-runner esbuild`. I also noticed that changes of the code are picked up immediately but changing the hash-bang requires you to delete `node_modules` first and then run `yarn install`